# How do I query in Elasticsearch when there is a relationship present?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5.1

I have two Models:

- Post
- Category

Each post has at least 1 category and this relationship is shown with a pivot table that contains the post id and category id.

I've already made code to query for the keyword, but I still can't think of a way for me to include the category in the search.

In my Post Model:

```
use ElasticquentTrait;

protected $mappingProperties = array(
    'id' => [
        'type' => 'integer',
    ],
    'name' => [
        'type' => 'string',
        "analyzer" => "standard",
    ],
    'description' => [
        'type' => 'string',
        "analyzer" => "standard",
    ],
    'address' => [
        'type' => 'string',
        "analyzer" => "standard",
    ],
);
```

And this is the code for the search query:

```
$search_results = BusinessListing::searchByQuery([
    'multi_match' => [
        'query' => $search_term,
        'fields' => [ "name^5", "description", "address"],
        'fuzziness' => "AUTO"
    ],
]);
```

One solution I had in mind was just to filter out the results with laravel and remove the ones with the non-matching categories, but I don't think that is the optimal solution for this.

I am using the [elasticquent/elasticquent](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/elasticquent/elasticquent) library.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!